# Integral of polynomial related to prime divisors

Tags: calculus, number-theory

Given the following integral $I_{m,n}=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^n)^m \mathrm{d}x$. Prove that for any fixed $n$ and for any $m$ $I_{m,n}$ is a rational number and when written in the form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q$ coprime, $p$ has the same set of prime divisors as has $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ I_{m,n}=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^m x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(m+1)\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{n\,\Gamma\left(m+1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\frac{m!}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}\left(k+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\tag{1}$$
gives:
$$ I_{m,n}=\frac{m! n^m}{\prod_{k=1}^{m}(nk+1)}=\prod_{k=1}^{m}\frac{nk}{nk+1} \tag{2}$$
and the problem boils down to proving that $m!$ is a divisor of $\prod_{k=1}^{m}(nk+1)$.

Sketch of the proof: assuming that $1\leq a \leq m$ and $\gcd(a,n)=1$, $n$ is invertible $\!\!\pmod{a}$, hence for some $k<a$ we have $nk+1\equiv 0\pmod{a}$.